# Why does gevent.spawn not execute the parameterized function until a call to Greenlet.join?

Tags: python, asynchronous, gevent

I'd like to issue an asynchronous HTTP POST request using `gevent` -- I don't care about the response, I simply want to execute the request as soon as possible. However, whenever I attempt to do so using `gevent.spawn`, the request never executes. I know this because calling the `.ready()` or `.successful()` methods on the `Greenlet` that is returned from `gevent.spawn` always returns `False`.

However, the Greenlet *has* started, because if I call `glet = gevent.spawn(...)`, then `glet.start()`, I get an error saying `AssertionError: Greenlet already started`.

The only time I get a `glet.ready() == True` is when I call `glet.join()`, but this is a blocking operation. How can I have the Greenlet execute without waiting for it to complete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since greenlets are cooperative, your new greenlet won't run until you yield to it. After calling spawn, call `gevent.sleep(0)` to yield and your greenlet should run.

It will continue to run until it does something that causes it to yield (like kicking off that http req). Then your other code can resume again.

EDIT:

To address your question about `grequests`, the `grequests.send()` doc says:

```
send(r, pool=None, stream=False)
    Sends the request object using the specified pool. If a pool isn't
    specified this method blocks. Pools are useful because you can specify size
    and can hence limit concurrency
```

Since you have not specified a pool, the request blocks for your greenlet to finish. In other words, once it returns the greenlet has already completed. To get the response, see `glt.get()` of the returned greenlet.

Comment: Ah that seems to work! However, when I'm using the grequests (https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) library, calling grequests.send(grequests.request("POST", <url>)) creates a Greenlet, but this Greenlet doesn't execute even after calling gevent.sleep(). Do you know why that is?